# Accessing ftp service from web-browser based terminal using REPL

Tags: node.js, socket.io, read-eval-print-loop

Just for tweaking with node.js, I am developing an app for accessing terminal from browser.. When I run ftp service from browser, following is the problem faced..

```
$ ftp
> o <Enter>
<Enter>
>  localhost<Enter>
<Enter>
```

It does not pushes the console output to the socket.io connection,
also after every FTP command, I have to press ENTER key twice, I think its because of the console output issue on REPL.
Following is my code...

```
startRepl();
execCmd("ftp");

function execCmd(command) {
        if (env.WEB_SHELL) {
            proc = spawn(env.WEB_SHELL, null, { cwd: cwd, env: env });
            stdin = proc.stdin;
            stdin.write(command);
            stdin.end();
        } else {
            proc = spawn(cmd, args, { cwd: cwd, env: env });
            stdin = proc.stdin;
        }

        proc.stdout.setEncoding("utf8");
        proc.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
            socket.emit("console", data+"\n");
        });

        proc.stderr.setEncoding("utf8");
        proc.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
            if (data.indexOf("execvp():") === 0) {
                data = cmd + ": command not found";
            }
            socket.emit("console", data+"\n");
        });

        proc.on("close", function () {
            stdin = null;
            socket.emit("exit", "");
        });
    }

    function startRepl() {
        var input   = streams.ReplStream(),
            output  = streams.ReplStream();

        input.setEncoding("utf8");
        output.setEncoding("utf8");

    replSrv = repl.start({
            prompt: "> ",
            input: input,
            output: output,
            terminal: false,
            useColors: true
        });

        stdin = input;
        output.on("data", function (data) {
            socket.emit("console", data+"\n");
        });

        replSrv.on("exit", function () {
            stdin = null;
            socket.emit("configure", {
                prompt      : cwd,
                promptChar  : promptChar
            });
            socket.emit("exit");
            replSrv = null;
        });

        socket.emit("configure", {
            prompt      : "",
            promptChar  : "> "
        });
    }
```